# Table is not Mapped In HQL query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

My class begins with:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "validate_info", catalog = "company")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class ValidateInfo implements java.io.Serializable{
```

And my HQL Query:

```
        List<ValidateInfo> lResult = null;

        String lHql = " from ValidateInfo vi "
                        + " where vi.document.idDocument in (:documentsList) "
                        + " and vi.idEntityType = :idEntityType";

        Query lQuery = pSession.createQuery(lHql);
        lQuery.setParameterList("documentsList", pDocumentsList);
        lQuery.setParameter("idEntityType", pIdEntityType);
        lResult = lQuery.list();
```

The error I get:

```
[T0028][SEVER] .web.Control.execute() RunService returns Exception  ValidateInfo is not mapped [ from ValidateInfo vi  where vi.document.idDocument in (:documentsList)  and vi.idEntityType = :idEntityType]
[T0028][SEVER] .web.Control.manageError()  java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

Can you guys help me? I don't know why i get the "not Mapped" error, the name of the HQL query table is the same as the classname.

Answer (score 2):

When you write an `HQL` query you must write the complete path of your used class.

So you can replace your code as follow:

```
String lHql = " from " + ValidateInfo.class.getName() + " vi "
+ " where vi.document.idDocument in (:documentsList) "
+ " and vi.idEntityType = :idEntityType";
```

Comment: But what I don't get is that for example if I make an HQL Query with another table I don't need what you put. For example "from Driver where idDriver = 1234", this one works perfectly

Comment: @Martinez If you use an alias, you must explicit the right path

Comment: I just don't get why I have to use this on this table but not on "Driver" 's table for example, if both are exactly the same.

Comment: @Martinez In your Validation example you're ugins alias vi, in your Driver example no. Not the same thing